# conditionally filtering values in a group based on two variables in a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to conditionally filter a data frame.

Here is an simple example of my data frame:

```
 library(dplyr)
head(FG_Pitchers_2002_2016)
        Players     Year         Team Start-IP Relief-IP Position
    Zack Segovia 2009    Nationals      0.0      10.1       RP
    Zack Segovia 2007     Phillies      5.0       0.0       SP
    Zack Wheeler 2014         Mets    185.1       0.0       SP
    Zack Wheeler 2013         Mets    100.0       0.0       SP
    Zeke Spruill 2014 Diamondbacks      5.1      17.1       RP
    Zeke Spruill 2013 Diamondbacks      7.0       4.1       SP
```

What I want to do is get the `Players` who have played both `SP` and `RP`. 
So, the output should be this:

```
    Players    Year         Team     Start-IP  Relief-IP  Position
Zack Segovia 2009    Nationals      0.0      10.1       RP
Zack Segovia 2007     Phillies      5.0       0.0       SP
Zeke Spruill 2014 Diamondbacks      5.1      17.1       RP
Zeke Spruill 2013 Diamondbacks      7.0       4.1       SP
```

The reason Zack Wheeler is filtered out is because, in the `Position` column, he is only listed as `SP`. Zack Segovia & Zeke Spruill both stay because they have both have `RP` and `SP` in the `Position` column.

I've tried a number of different ways of doing this. Mainly I've been trying to group by Name and then filter, but that hasn't been working. An example of some of the code I've experimented with:

```
    FG_Pitchers_2002_2016_1 <- FG_Pitchers_2002_2016 %>% 
group_by(Players) %>% 
filter(Position == "RP" | Position == "SP") %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

Would anybody know how to generate this output?

Comment: Can `Position` have more than these two categories?  If not, how about `filter(n_distinct(Position) == 2)`?

Comment: Yes, these were the only two categories and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I tried:

```
df %>% group_by(Players) %>%
    mutate(wRP = any(Position == 'RP'),
           wSP = any(Position == 'SP')) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(wRP == T, wSP == T) %>%
    select(-wRP, -wSP)
```

Based on comment of aosmith:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Players) %>%
    filter(all(c('RP', 'SP') %in% Position))
```

or

```
df %>%
    group_by(Players) %>%
    filter(any(Position == 'SP') & any(Position == 'RP'))
```

Comment: You could also do `filter(any(Position == "SP") & any(Position == "RP") )` directly without the intermediary steps.

Comment: @aosmith, thanks for suggestion and  I edited the post.